# What's the name of this Indian dish I had?

Tags: indian-cuisine, food-identification

I had a dish recently at an Indian restaurant called Andhra(?) chicken. 
It was written in marker so I'm not sure about the h in there.

The dish consisted of breaded pieces of chicken that were fried and then seemingly cooked in some spice mixture definitely containing:

- green chili
- egg
- curry leaves
- fennel seed
- cumin?

I tried looking up Andhra chicken online but all the recipes seem to have some sort of sauce component to it, while this dish was definitely dry.

Does anyone have any idea what that dish could have been, and where I can find a recipe online for it?

Comment: Looking for `andhra chicken -curry` pn Google gives a lot of *dry* results. Though I've never had it before, it seems to be fried chicken cooked [andhra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andhra_Pradesh) style, a south-eastern state of India.

Answer (score 4):

I guess that you have tasted chicken 65, which is a dish from Andhra Pradesh. Chicken 65 is also known as Andhra chicken. It is fried and coated with spices. You can Google chicken 65 recipe. I hope my guess for that may right.

Comment: The colour was a lot less red, and more of a brownish colour. Also, there were noticeable bits of egg on the outside of the chicken. Would this just have been some variation by the restaurant itself?

Answer (score 1):

Since the chicken is breaded I would guess **Kodi Vepudu**

[image]

Comment: This looks really close! The only difference is there's no visible egg on this and that dish did not have cilantro. I suppose that could just have been how the restaurant prepared it? Is adding egg a common feature in these types of dishes?

Comment: There is so much variety in Indian cuisine that anything is possible.  Over the years I've seen egg added to pretty much every chicken dish at one time or another.   Some will leave it relatively dry like this, others will serve it much more wet with sauce.  Not drowning in a bath of curry, but wet with sauce.  This dish, Chicken 65 and Chili Chicken are all very similar with some small differences in the specific spices used but this is the only one of the 3 that I've seen where the chicken is breaded rather than just fried.